# Set HTML dropdown options from PHP variable

Tags: php, html, html-select

I want to set the  on a HTML dropdown menu from a php variable. I give you my code so you can see I want to do:

```
<?php
$html_table = '
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>';
while($arr = pg_fetch_array($result1))
{
$html_table .= "<tr><td> $arr[0] </td></tr>";                          
}
$html_table .='</tr>';
?>

<p>
<select name="db" size="1">
<option> $html_table </option>  #### <- that is my question, how to get that working
</select>
</p>
```

I hope you understand what I want to do. If you know about nicer ways, let me know.
Cheers

Comment: You can't put a table inside an `<option>`. Just put a series of `<option>` elements, each with one element of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$options = '';
while($arr = pg_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $options .= '<option>'.$arr[0].'</option>';                          
}
?>

<p>
<select name="db" size="1">
    <?php echo $options; ?>
</select>
</p>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Options not displaying?

Comment: Yes, sorry, should have mentioned that... There's no option to see in the dropdown menu

Comment: In `while` loop use `var_dump($arr)`. Update your code. Maybe there is no results?

Comment: Done - there are results.

Comment: Now it works. I jumbled all your hints, but now I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `$html_table` with `<?php echo $html_table; ?>` and you're good to go - from the PHP point of view that is. HTML is of course invalid, as pointed out by others.

Answer (score 0):

First: you didn't close your `<table>` tag.

Second: you can't paste`<table>` tag into `<select>`. You should put a series of `<option`> elements, each with one element of the array.

Third: To print PHP variable you should do like this:

```
<option><?php echo $html_table; ?></option>
```

But again: it will break your HTML, because table can't be inside select option.
The best solution is:

```
<select name="db" size="1">
    <?php while ($arr = pg_fetch_array($result1)): ?>
        <option><?php echo $arr[0]; ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

so set your option elements like this

```
<option value="<?php echo $html_table; ?>"><?php echo $html_table; ?></option>
```

just know, an option can't be a table.